# Всегда ли можно правильно прочитать, понять и записать школьный диктант?

Tags: стилистика

На одном из учительских сайтов мне попался диктант, прельстивший меня сначала большим количеством орфограмм. Но при дальнейшем знакомстве оказалось, что не все предложения я могу прочитать хотя бы с какой-то интонацией, а еще позже выяснилось, что их смысл я понимаю с третьего раза и только в письменном виде, но на слух точно не напишу.

Как можно оценить приведенные ниже предложения? Это просто плохой стиль, или можно назвать конкретные стилистические ошибки? Или там всё хорошо и правильно, и все диктанты такие?

(1) Чисто выметенная и еще сырая от недавно стаявшего снега улица была пустынна, но красива выдержанной, немного тяжелой красотой.

(1) Большие белые дома с лепными украшениями по карнизам и в простенках между окнами, окрашенные в тонко-розоватый оттенок весенними лучами заходящего солнца, смотрели на свет божий сосредоточенно и важно.

(2) Перед ним внизу стояло целое море воды, холодно блестевшее в лучах солнца, далеко на горизонте медленно опускавшегося в него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пустынна, но красива.** Не противопоставление, к тому же улица не бывает пустынна, а лишь безлюдна. **Красива ... красотой**. Просто красота! **Окрашенные в оттенок**. Тонко. **На свет Божий**. Без комментария. Целое **море воды** с солнцем внутри - шедевр.

Comment: Да, замечания справедливые.

Answer (score 1):

> Но при дальнейшем знакомстве оказалось, что не все предложения я могу
>   прочитать хотя бы с какой-то интонацией, а еще позже выяснилось, что
>   их смысл я понимаю с третьего раза...

Наверное, вы просто немного устали. Утром проснётесь -- и всё придёт в норму.

**P.S.**

Все приведённые в диктанте предложения -- от М. Горького.

Comment: Так подписывать диктанты надо, я бы тогда была бы снисходительнее (как надзиратель Очумелов у Чехова в "Хамелеоне").  Образность, художественность бы оценила. Может быть, читать такой текст надо частями и только зрительно, по-моему, они (эти части)  как бы существуют отдельно. Вот, к примеру, предложение (2). Ну как можно   распространенное несогласованное определение ставить перед обособленным согласованным определением!  Или в предложении (3) непонятно к чему относится местоимение "него" – к солнцу или морю.  В общем, если не плохой стиль, то тяжеловесный какой-то, трудно читаемый.

Comment: А кстати, вот интересная информация. Впервые напечатано в газете «Волгарь», 1893, номер 259, 31 октября. Первый рассказ из серии «Маленькие истории», печатавшейся в нижегородской газете «Волгарь» осенью-зимой 1893–1894 года. В собрания сочинений рассказ не включался.  (Первый напечатанный рассказ Горького «Макар Чудра» вышел в 1892 году).  Поэтому это раннее творчество писателя, возможно, он и сам не ценил высоко этот рассказ.